# PHP - Request language from URL

Tags: php

I'm using this code (shown below) to get multiple languages on my website. The problem is; every time a new visitor goes to my site, the first time (because of the cookie request) the visitor gets a blank page. After the visitor refreshes the page once, it's all okay. So I wanted to make something that the visitor can request their own preferred language using a URL beside the current method (I currently use a form to choose languages). (Something like `?lang=DE`.) But how should I do it?

**Code:**

```
<?PHP
ob_start (); 
$aTalen = array ("General", "Nederland", "België", "Belgien", "Belgique", "Belgium", "France", "Deutschland", "India", "Polska", "UK", "España", "Fryslân");

if (isset ($_POST['kiezen'])) 
{ 
    setcookie ("taal", $_POST['taalkeuze'], time()+60*60*24*7*52, "/", ".test.com");
    header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

} 
if (!isset ($_COOKIE['taal'])) 
{ 
    setcookie ("taal", "General", time()+60*60*24*7*52, "/", ".test.com");
} 
elseif (!in_array ($_COOKIE['taal'], $aTalen)) 
{ 
    setcookie ("taal", "General", time()+60*60*24*7*52, "/", ".test.com"); 
} 
else 
{
    include ("/languages/" . $_COOKIE['taal'] . ".lang.php"); 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Query strings are handled by the `$_GET[]` superglobal array.  The implementation of your language switcher is up to you, but that should point you in the right direction

Comment: @Mik Roe Hollywood Games whats your site's navigation flow? Is it like you go to index.php and there you check to see if the lang cookie is available. if it does you load the language and show the page. If the cookie is not there you redirect to a language selection page. and when the user selects and submits the preferred language it sets a cookie and redirect back to the index?

Comment: As Major Productions LLC suggested use $_GET[variable] in your script to get what you want. As far a cookie as an option you don't needed it if you associate all internal links with that parameter. Some browsers/users have switch off cookies.

Comment: @MajorProductionsLLC Do you have an example? I'm pretty new, so I don't know where/how to do it.

Comment: @AmilaDev I've imported a `setcookie` on every page using PHP include. So it doesn't matter which page the visitor first visits. It always sets a language (after a reload). When people want to change their language, they should to to the settings page, and if they apply their chosen language, the page reloads its self; `header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);`.

Comment: @MikRoeHollywoodGames please check the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is correct but looks like the problem is with the way you've implemented it.

Instead of having cookie check on every page, you can put that into your bootstrap script or something similar. We also don't need to check for the cookie every time. We can check once and store the language in a session variable.

```
<?php
session_start();

$languages = array('jerman','french','english');

$language = 'english';

if(!isset($_SESSION['lang']))
{
    // check for the cookie
    if(isset($_COOKIE['lang']))
    {
         if(in_array($_COOKIE['lang'], $languages))
         {
               $language = $_COOKIE['lang'];
               $_SESSION['lang'] = $_COOKIE['lang'];
         }
    }
}
else
{
    $language = $_SESSION['lang'];
}

require 'languages/'.$language.'.lang.php';
```

Above code we have started the session, then we've defined an array for storing languages we support. $language variable stores the default language. then we check if the language is set in the session. if it isn't we check to see if there is a language cookie. if the cookie is there and its value matches one of our supported languages we've created a session variable representing that language as well as overridden the default language.

If the language was already set in the session we assign that value to $language variable again overriding the default language.

Finally we've used that language variable along with the require construct to include the relevant language file.

To let users change their language you can for example create a set of links as follows:

```
<a href="language.php?lang=german">German</a>
<a href="language.php?lang=french">French</a>
<a href="language.php?lang=english">English</a>
```

Then in your language.php script, you can add below code to handle language changes.

```
$languages = array('jerman','french','english');

if(isset($_GET['lang']))
{
    if(in_array($_GET['lang'], $languages))
    {
         $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
         setcookie('lang', $_GET['lang'], time()+60*60*24*7*52, "/", ".test.com");
    }
}

header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

What we've done is checking to see if $_GET['lang'] is set, if it is so we've done one more test to see if the language is in our supported list of languages. If that is true we've added the language to a session variable. We also created a cookie and finally redirect the user to the page that he was in.

Try and see if you can get this to work.

### Update

Your language file can look like this: eg: english.lang.php

```
<?php
$lang['main_heading'] = 'This is My Heading';
$lang['sub_heading'] = 'This is My Sub Heading';
$lang['special_notice'] = 'Special Notice'];
```

You can repeat this same mechanism in other language files as well. You have to maintain the key names just the values should be set according to the language. Then after loading the language file you can use its values as shown below:

```
<h1><?php echo $lang['main_heading'] ?></h1>
<h3><?php echo $lang['sub_heading'] ?></h3>
<p><?php echo $lang['special_notice'] ?></p>
```

Try changing the language and you'll see the headings, notices getting changed to the language you've selected.

Comment: It looks really good, but.. I'm pretty new to PHP etc. so how would I combine/replace this with my  current method?

Comment: @Mik Roe Hollywood Games You can simply replace your language checking/loading code with the one I suggested above. If it is for every page you can put that code into a separate script and include it on every page. Then create a separate language.php for switching languages.

Comment: I've done that. Created a new language.php in my parts folder, and a language.php in my root directory. But I don't think I need 2 separate files, do I? Because, when I then tried the links like: `<a href="language.php?lang=german">German</a>`, nothing happened.. Just a refresh and that's it.

Comment: @MikRoeHollywoodGames Not at all. You don't need to have two separate language.php scripts. Just the one at root directory should be sufficient. Its purpose is to simply set the 'lang' value in the session. Then when you load your index.php or whatever page it should handle the language loading with the code I posted at the top.

Comment: I've followed the steps. The language stays the same after I use the link..

Comment: @MikRoeHollywoodGames how's your specific language file looks like? show me a sample to look at

Comment: The file with al the languages (with text)? Or the bridge-like files, like yours?

Comment: @MikRoeHollywoodGames I have updated the answer you can follow the same.